# NetSuite Saved Search formula to get a field's value as of a given date

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am required to use a saved search to answer the question: how many cancelled Sales Orders did we have on a specified date?   I must use a saved search because ultimately it will be something viewed on a dashboard (and this is what the end users are used to).  I know that I can and how to complete via SuiteScript; this is explicitly a question related to Saved Searches and/or SuiteAnalytics.  The status of our sales orders fluctuates more than a “normal company”, i.e. 1 SO might change status 3 or 4 times before being “done”.  My initial thought was to create a saved search and add “System Notes fields…” as results.  So I’d have something like the following:

[image: Image of Saved Search Results]

For the given date 7/19/20 the status was “Canceled” since 7/19/20 is greater than 6/12/20 and less than 7/22/20.  I would like to get this field’s value on 7/19/20 programmatically and display it as a Saved Search results column but I don’t know how.  I think I’m stuck because I don’t know how to tell NetSuite in a saved search to look at the date in the row above or below.  Said differently I don’t know how to compare the given date to all the system note dates to find the system note date that is right before (use the old value) or after (use the new value) the given date.  In excel I would do the following, how do i do this in a NetSuite Saved Search?

[image: Image of Excel Calculation]

Answer (score -1):

To apply a dynamic date filter:

1. In the Criteria tab, add a date filter:
   Filter = System Notes : Date is on today
2. In the Available Filters tab, add the same date filter:
   Filter = System Notes : Date,
   Show in Filter Region = Yes